# Server name in views are causing build issues in Sql Server Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server Project in which I have a View

```
SELECT * FROM [Tracking].[dbo].[Document_tb]
```

This is causing a build issue

> [dbo].[TrackerDocumentTable_vw] has an unresolved reference to object
>   [Tracking].[dbo].[Document_tb].   C:projects\Schema
>   Objects\Schemas\dbo\Views\TrackerDocumentTable_vw.sql 4.

The same query is in SPs and TVFs but they are not throwing any exceptions. I have tried to change build method to "not in build" that solves my problem partially, but while schema compare it is excluding this file. Is there any specific reason why VS is throwing an exception on views but not in SPs and TVFs?

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the source of that view

Comment: That looks to be a database reference, not a server. Do you have database project for the `Tracking` database in your solution? I can't say why you don't get the reference issue with other objects like this but normally one must add a database project reference for other databases and use the associated SQLCMD variable for the referenced database instead of the actual name, like `[$(TrackingDatabaseName)].[dbo].[Document_tb]`.

Comment: I got this db project from a client, maybe it is the database project, but my only concern is why it is only throwing an exception on Views, not on SPs and TVFs

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to deferred name resolution that applies to stored procedures and multi-valued table functions. Referenced objects do not need to exist at creation time as long as the syntax is correct.

However views and other function types store metadata e.g. column information, and therefore require the referenced objects to exist at compile time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

References to objects that can not be found for sp and functions are treated as warnings for views as errors (check the Errors tab and the warning tab).

Why is this so, probably because in sql server we can create a procedure that I refer to
a non-existent object, but for the view is not allow. You can set up in visual studio that it would be treated as a error as well.